# Phonegap / Cordova Filetransfer - acessing option param values from java servlet

Tags: java, android, cordova, servlets, phonegap-plugins

How to access **options.param** values and **upload ImageURI** to a **java servlet**. below is my phonegap code to upload imageURI to a java servlet captured from camera.

```
   var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey="file";
   options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.jpg';
   options.mimeType="image/jpeg";     
   options.params = {
           value1: 10,
           value2: 30          
       }    

   var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://myserver/uploadImageFile"), fileUploadSucess, fileUploadFail, options);
```

http://myserver/uploadImageFile is the java servlet path, can any one provide me with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just get them on the `doPost` with `req.getParameter`

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String value1 = req.getParameter("value1");
    String value2 = req.getParameter("value2");

}
```